# ios10 Swift 3 - [Generic] Creating an image format with an unknown type is an error

Tags: uiimage, swift3, ios10

I am trying to convert my selected image to base64 and then upload to the server but I seem to be getting a strange error when I go into the image picker I get the error  Creating an image format with an unknown type is an error

```
@IBAction func selectImage(_ sender: AnyObject) {


        selectImage.allowsEditing = true //2
        selectImage.sourceType = .photoLibrary //3
        present(selectImage, animated: true, completion: nil)//4


    }



func imagePickerController(_ selectImage: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
            let chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as! UIImage //2

            profilePic.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit //3
            profilePic.image = chosenImage //4

            let quality = 1.0
            base64String = (UIImageJPEGRepresentation(chosenImage, CGFloat(quality))?.base64EncodedString())!
            //print (base64String)

            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) //5
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing `AnyObject` to `Any` in the pickers delegate function?
The correct syntax for swift3 is:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController,
                               didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    if let chosenImage =  info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting that error in the simulator at the moment an image has been tapped in the picker, but BEFORE the user has confirmed the selection by tapping the "Choose" button.  That said, the app otherwise appears for all outward appearances to be working properly.

Since the user can also hit "Cancel" but remain in the picker (so tapping another image gives the same error on the console, before control has returned to the app), I suspect the issue is in Apple's code (at least when running in the simulator).